# Return MPI::Request[] type from JNI and access elements of Request in Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, mpi, return-type

I'm looking to return an MPI::Request[] type from a native C++ function to Java (via JNI) and subsequently access elements in the MPI::Request[] array from the Java side.

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_mpiJNI_mpiTEST(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
   MPI::Request req[8];
   return req;  // Error: Can't convert req to jobjectArray type
}
```

The only return types I know of that would be close are jobjectArrays and this does not work.  Java doesn't know what an MPI::Request[] type is.

I've not wanted to use things like MPJ or MPIJava because I don't know that there is much support for future MPI work in Java and want to have code that will persist through many cluster updates and configurations.  If someone knows more about this matter I would be interested to hear more.

Comment: please tell us how this relates to c++

Comment: The java native code is written in C++.  MPI commands are coming from C++ and need to be passed back to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a JNI type of type jobjectArray. JNI will not convert that req pointer to a jobjectArray for you. Also note that how java lays out object arrays and

First off, you are allocating an array on the C++ stack. This is not a persistent memory and thus *req* pointer will be garbage when your JNI method returns. So if you want to preserve or allocate the native array storage, you will need to allocate the memory with 'new' and have a persistent pointer to your array.

What I would suggest, is that instead of returning and creating a object array, you return a single "pointer" value back to java to the begining of the the Request array, just like you would do in C++.

In order to preserve a native pointer inside a Java object, the typical trick is to convert the pointer to a java 'long' primitive type, which is long enough to hold the actual native address on most platforms. The store the return 'long' in your java class as field.

Next time you need access to the native MPI::Request array, you make a call to a native java method and pass it the address value stored as 'long' and in you corresponding JNI method, convert the JNI *jlong* parameter back to a pointer and typecast it to MPI::Request *req and thus you will have successfully created the request in your java/jni method, returned it, and stored inside a java class and then again used it natively in a second method where you can make the C++ calls to create/send those requests and so on.

Lastly, since you dynamically allocated the native memory for the MPI::Result[], remember to make another java native method that will again convert the long value to a pointer and release the memory with C++ delete statement, after you no longer need that array. Otherwise you will have a memory leak.

So here is how I would rewrite your JNI method:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_mpiJNI_mpiTEST(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
   MPI::Request *req = new MPI::Request[8]; // Don't forget to release memory leater

   uintptr_t storage = (uintptr_t)ptr

   return (jlong) storage;
}
```

Comment: This is an incredibly good answer to my question!  Thank you very much!